# Как передать картинку Intent'ом?

Tags: java, android

Подключился к камере с помощью API. Когда вызываю функцию

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
```

мне возвращается массив `byte[] data`. Если я все правильно понимаю, то это и есть наша фотография.

Как мне этот массив байтов `Intent`ом передать и установить полученную картинку в следующем активити?

Comment: Плохая идея. Надо сохранять изображение в файл, а в `Intent` передавать путь. Если будете передавать `byte[]`, то будут тормоза. А в худшем случае система просто закроет приложение.

Comment: А можно как то конвертировать этот массив в Bitmap и передавать уже его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот таким образом все работает
Во первых отправляем Intent

```
public void takePicture(View view) {
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

Intent intent = new Intent(context, AcceptNotAccept.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", data);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

В нужном классе получаем Intent

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_accept_not_accept);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

bitmap = rotate(bitmap, 90);
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivForAcceptPicture)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private Bitmap rotate(Bitmap b, int degrees) {
    if (degrees != 0 && b != null) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) b.getWidth() / 2, (float) b.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
            if (b != b2) {
                b.recycle();
                b = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Вот так все работает у меня

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: как только я добавляю эту строчку в методе                                        public void takePicture(View view) { 
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

               //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);                                                 то показывает ошибку в методе    Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        camera = Camera.open(CAMERA_ID);
        setPreviewSize(FULL_SCREEN);
    }

Comment: Почему может быть эта ошибка?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshenko покажите код в одном виде, может вы`}` забыли? И что за ошибку дает?

Comment: Только что все получилось... Нашел решение здесь stackoverflow.com/questions/13758560/… , но теперь получается, что изображение с камеры правильное, а когда сохраняет то повернутое... Наверное есть функция которая должна переворачивать картинку в правильное положение перед сохранением...

Comment: @AlekseyTimochshenko получите положение телефона, думаю поможет

Comment: Ок, а после того как я получу положение телефона, что делать?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko если у вас есть положение телефона и фото, вы будете знать как снимали фото. И можете сказать, нужно ли поворачивать рисунок или нет